# Pandas dataframe convert multiple rows and columns to single row[key] and column[key]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I need to convert to a movielens type with `User ID, MovieId, Rating`.
The dataframe I have is in a dense form

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d={'user_id':[1,2], 'col1': [1, np.nan], 'col2': [np.nan, 4], 'col3': [np.nan, 3]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want it in the form:

```
user_id feature value
0   1.0 col1    1.0
1   1.0 col2    NaN
2   1.0 col3    NaN
3   2.0 col1    NaN
4   2.0 col2    4.0
5   2.0 col3    3.0
```

I wrote a small function to accomplish this:

```
def func(df_x):
    
    df_temp=pd.DataFrame()
    for index, row in df_x.iterrows():
        for cols in df_x.columns:
            if 'user_id' in cols:
                continue
            d_n={'user_id':row['user_id'], 'feature': cols, 'value': row[cols]}
            df_temp = df_temp.append(pd.DataFrame(d_n, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)

    return df_temp
```

This seem to work for small datasets but for larger datasets, this approach seem to be taking a long time. For a 14500 * 60 dataset I have, the cell on the notebook dint finish executing after running through the night (On my 16GB Laptop).
Can you please suggest an optimal way to handle this?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `melt` then `sort_values`

```
out = df.melt('user_id').sort_values('user_id')
Out[397]: 
   user_id variable  value
0        1     col1    1.0
2        1     col2    NaN
4        1     col3    NaN
1        2     col1    NaN
3        2     col2    4.0
5        2     col3    3.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying now.

Comment: Thats just super. It worked. Thanks. It is not allowing me to accept the answer immediately. Will wait and accept the answer in a but. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShekarTippur no problem, happy coding